# Is there a way to assign a multi-line string to a object property?

Tags: autohotkey

I know that you can assign a multi-line string to a variable like this:

```
MyVar = 
(
this
is 
a 
string with multiple
lines
)
```

But is there a way to assign the above string to an object property? I tried doing it like this but I received an error:

```
Array := {}
Array["key"] = 
(
this
is 
a 
string with multiple
lines
)
```

The error says:

> The following variable name contains an illegal character 
>   "this 
>   is 
>   a
>   string"

I just want to be able to open my script in a text editor and copy and paste multiple-line strings directly into the editor as properties of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the proper assignment operator := with Objects, likewise your text needs be enclosed by Quotes.

Try:

```
obj := {}

obj["key"] := 
( 
"this
is 
a 
string with multiple
lines"
)

MsgBox % obj["key"]
```

Or you can do this below:

```
x = 
(
this
is 
a 
string with multiple
lines
)

obj["key"] := x

MsgBox % obj["key"]
```

You can also build a multi-line object like so:

```
obj := {"key": 
(
"this
is 
a 
string with multiple
lines"
)}

MsgBox % obj["key"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a raw multiline string assignment like the following it tends to defeat any indenting you may have cultivated in your script.

```
str := {"Lines":
(
"first
second
third"
)}
```

Although that will work. If you're looking to preserve your code indenting then you can create a multiline string by delimiting the lines with `n like this:

```
str := {"Lines": "first`nSecond`nThird"}
```

Comment: Both of your examples are wrong, you have to include quotes around text in when assigning, like you did in your second example, although your delimiters are wrong in that example (unless they are changed from the default which are `n but that wasn't specified and most users wouldn't do that).