# Auto-hotkey - use a multiline code as a variable to insert in a file

Tags: autohotkey

I've found the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558551/is-there-a-way-to-assign-a-multi-line-string-to-a-object-property) in Stack-Overflow which is related to mine, but the solution didn't work for me.

I would like to compile an AHK script which opens a file in Notepad++ and inserts a code at a specific line. I've got the AHK script to work with a normal string, but it doesn't work with the code I'm trying to use.

I would like to insert the following code in a file using notepad++

```
<Macro name="Remove Navis folders" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
<Action type="0" message="2318" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
<Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /></Macro>"
```

And here's my script

```
    obj := {"key": 
(
    <Macro name="Remove Navis folders" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
<Action type="0" message="2318" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
<Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /></Macro>
)}

Run, notepad++.exe %A_AppData%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml
Sleep, 200
Send, ^{Home}
Send, ^f
Sleep, 200
Sendraw, <Macros>
Send, {ENTER}{ESC}{Right}
Sleep, 200
Send, {ENTER}{Tab}
Sleep, 200
Send, % obj["key"]
```

Comment: Some comments (tips) - 1: you don't have to compile in order to run a script (just so you know). 2: you don't need to use an editor to manipulate files, you can use FileRead + StringReplace + FileAppend to create a modified (new) file. 3: You can loop through all files in a folder or just a specific set of files. 4: if you have more "file editing needs" there is a Text File library with plenty of functions that may be of interest, called TF, code on GitHub here https://github.com/hi5/TF

Comment: Thank you for the tips. 1: But I would like to compile the script to share it with other colleagues who don't have AHK installed. 2: I want it to work only with notepad++. But the FileRead and other functions are really informative. Thanks for that. 3&4: Really thanks for the links. I might need those someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put entire text in " and escape " that are part of the code otherwise there is an error.

```
obj := {"key": 
(
"<Macro name=""Remove Navis folders"" Ctrl=""no"" Alt=""no"" Shift=""no"" Key=""0"">
<Action type=""0"" message=""2318"" wParam=""0"" lParam=""0"" sParam="""" />
<Action type=""3"" message=""1700"" wParam=""0"" lParam=""0"" sParam="""" /></Macro>"""
)}

MsgBox % obj["key"]
```